# What type of cedar wood was used to build the Bais Hamikdash?

Tags: words, beis-hamikdash, trees

Related [Acacia wood or Cedar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89487/5120)

We see that ארז (cedar) was used for the Bais Hamikdash [Melachim 1 9:11](http://sefaria.org/I_Kings.9.11)

And we see that there are many types of ארז (cedar) [Bava Basra 80b](http://sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.80b.17)  and [Midrash Tanchuma Teruma](http://sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Terumah.9.16)

Which type was of ארז was used?